# Simple Haskell Average Function Gives Couldn't Match Type Error

Tags: haskell

All the other average questions I've seen are much more complicated than what I need. I am very new to Haskell and I'm currently working through The Craft of Functional Programming 2nd Edition.

In chapter 3 there is an exercise to write a simple function to average 3 integers. The function type signature is provided and I used it in my solution. I wrote:

```
averageThree :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
averageThree a b c = (a + b + c) / 3
```

I use ghci for compilation and when I try and load my file I get "Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type`Int'". How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a + b + c` will have type `Int`, and `/` is not even defined for `Int`.  GHC will probably infer that `3` has type `Float` though.  You have to explicitly cast the type in this situation, so you'd need to do

```
fromIntegral (a + b + c) / 3
```

The `fromIntegral` function takes an `Integral a => a` type like `Int` or `Integer` and converts it to a `Num b => b` type, which could also be `Int` or `Integral`, or `Float`, `Double`, `Complex Double`, and even custom numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Fractional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional), to support Real division:

```
averageThree :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a -> a
averageThree a b c = (a + b + c) / 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, which means `/` takes two fractional numbers of the same type and returns a fractional number of the same type. You are giving it an `Int` as an argument, which is not fractional, and asking for a `Float` as output. You must convert your `Int` to a `Float` before giving it to `/`. Use `fromIntegral :: Int -> Float`. `fromIntegral (a + b + c) / 3`. You could also leave off the type signature and ask ghci for the inferred type.